# How to install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll on Client Computer

Tags: .net, c++

I am dealing with some code that won't install on client machines (NOT running Visual Studio) because is makes reference to VSConstants.S_OK, which is in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll.  Is there a redistributable that includes this, or do I need to have the code updated to use a different constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll is parenthetically *not* a redistributable component.  You'll find a list of the ones you can redistribute in the redist.txt file in the Visual Studio install directory.

Getting rid of this particular dependency isn't hard.  It is a COM HRESULT value, S_OK = 0.  You can find those values listed in the WinError.h SDK header file.  For VS2008, you'll find it in the c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include.  Earlier releases in the vc\PlatformSDK subdirectory of the VS install directory.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the confirmation and additional info.